# My Sql print statement is not workinng

Tags: sql

How do I get this to work? If the count is higher for singles i would like it to output yes and then no for viceversa.

```
IF
select COUNT(StudMaritalStatus) from students WHERE StudMaritalStatus = "M"
<
select COUNT(StudMaritalStatus) from students WHERE StudMaritalStatus = "S"
Print 'Yes'
ELSE
Print 'No';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use `IF` inside a query, instead use a `CASE` expression with conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT
    CASE WHEN SUM(CASE WHEN StudMaritalStatus = 'M' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) <
              SUM(CASE WHEN StudMaritalStatus = 'S' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
         THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'No' END AS label
FROM students
```